# Can I use existing API and PayPal Payment gateway in two different domain?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using an API of a service provider. All details of services updated via this API in my database. Also, I am using PayPal Payment gateway. Now, I have to change my domain name. Can I use same database in my new domain?

If I run both existing & new website, will it impact on new domain?
Can I run both domain (existing & new)?

Which information I need to update in new domain so that I can use same API and PayPal payment gateway?

I just want to use existing API & Payment gateway in new domain. The content of both website will be unique. After making live new website, I will update the content.

Answer (score 0):

For processing PayPal payments on independent storefronts/domains, a best practice is for the PayPal invoice id (usually your own/internal order #) of every transaction to include a small 3 or 2-letter prefix that identifies which site it's from. So suppose you had a site called "Advanced", its invoice id could start at "ADV-10000" and count up from there, "ADV-10001", "ADV-10002" etc. This helps organize payments in your PayPal account and prevents the issue of duplicate payments being blocked if a store tries to use the same invoice_id that was previously used for a successful transaction by a different store. (By default PayPal will block attempts to capture a payment with an invoice_id that's already been used for a successful payment before, to prevent accidental duplicate orders)

There aren't any other issues with using PayPal on multiple domains. As long as whatever you're selling complies with PayPal's terms of service you're fine.